# using section types inside of blockquote

Tags: sectioning, quoting

I'm still new to latex, but can someone explain to me why this one works:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{quote}
\subsubsection{Just some Text}
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

but this one does not:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{quote}
\paragraph{Just some Text}
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

The second example results in the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

complete file is the following:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % provides \textsubscript
% use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\else % if luatex or xelatex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \ifxetex
    \usepackage{xltxtra,xunicode}
  \fi
  \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \newcommand{\euro}{€}
\fi
% use microtype if available
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{\usepackage{microtype}}{}
\ifxetex
  \usepackage[setpagesize=false, % page size defined by xetex
              unicode=false, % unicode breaks when used with xetex
              xetex]{hyperref}
\else
  \usepackage[unicode=true]{hyperref}
\fi
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true,
            bookmarks=true,
            pdfauthor={},
            pdftitle={},
            colorlinks=true,
            urlcolor=blue,
            linkcolor=magenta,
            pdfborder={0 0 0}}
\urlstyle{same}  % don't use monospace font for urls
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}  % prevent overfull lines
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\begin{quote}
\subsubsection{Just some Textj}
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

--- EDIT ----

In case anyone else is looking for a solution to this, I added the following to my preamble and it seems to work. If there is a better way please chime in.

```
% added to fix paragraphs and subparagraphs
\makeatletter
    \renewcommand\paragraph{%
        \@startsection{paragraph}{4}{0mm}%
            {-\baselineskip}%
            {.3\baselineskip}%
            {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
    \renewcommand\subparagraph{%
        \@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{0mm}%
            {-\baselineskip}%
            {.3\baselineskip}%
            {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: `quote` makes use of a list and then needs the first char to be a regular one, that is, you can not start a new paragraph there. For example, if you just use `\begin{quote} \ \paragraph{} ...` no error. But the result is not the wanted one.

Comment: @Sigur But then why does it work with `\subsubsection`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! You should move `lmodern` to the code executed only if `pdftex` is active. You should probably move `fontenc` as well. `fontspec` will set Latin Modern as default otherwise. Also, don't set `\parindent` and `\parskip` that way. Load the `parskip` package if necessary. Do you need to check for the existence of standard packages such as `microtype`?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome :)

It actually seems to work with `/section` `/subsection` and `/subsubsection`.
And it fails on `/paragraph`, `/subparagraph` `subsubparagraph` and below.

@cfr, thanks for the tips, I'll do some more reading and try out your suggestions. The file was actually generated by pandoc from a markdown file. The bit of markdown that the fragment resulted from was the following:

     `> ##### Just some Text`

So, if this is the incorrect way of getting the layout I want, can anyone point me in the direction of how to do it?

Comment: I don't know. Does `pandoc` let you customise the preamble?

Comment: I wasn't even sure what I should search for. Just ran across this though:

http://earthwithsun.com/questions/356032/markdown-to-latex-conversion-with-a-custom-preamble-using-pandoc

going to see what I can figure out, thanks again for responses.